# Missing detail on the object when baking normals

Tags: normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I have been having some trouble with normal baking . I am trying to make a die. After the bake is finished, I get the edge detail of the high poly mesh on the maps, but the numbers don't show up at all. I used the text object then converted it to a mesh and aligned everything to where it should be. 
[image]
When I used a boolean modifier to attach the numbers to my high poly die, the numbers showed up in the bake, but there were lots of artifacts. In my most recent attempt, I filled everything in (cut out the bottom faces of the numbers and attached them to the cube) to make it all one object. What can I do to get this map baked out right? Is this sort of thing even possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.Se. It seems there is no difference between the normals directions of the faces that constitute the number and the face of the dice itself. There are no details to bake there. Have you tried to bevel the edges of the numbers? Is it something showing up in the normal map in this case?